# Refresh List View programmatically within Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, expandablelistview, baseadapter

How to **refresh** *Child List* within `Expandable List View`

I am using following code to **delete** child list *item*, but `unable to refresh` Child Item List.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
private DBAdapter mydb;

    public SyncExpandablePendingListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ....

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_pending_list_item, null);
    }

    ....

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.d("oldList:", _listDataChild.toString());

                mydb.DeleteECRecord(data2);
                _listDataChild.remove(childPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.d("newList:", _listDataChild.toString());

    });

}

.............

}
```

Actually, I am not getting where I have to make the change ? What exactly I have missed ? :

Please let me know Where I am doing MISTAKE ? What I am MISSING ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed that entry from your database, but didn't remove it from the HashMap. Remove it from HashMap too and then call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I have tried this : _listDataChild.remove(childPosition); notifyDataSetChanged(); but I did not get any success

Comment: @Oreo Use debugging. Put breakpoint inside getChildView().  After notifying, check what is your new list in HashMap. Maybe HashMap is not updated that way and you have to put that modified list again corresponding to that key. Debugging will help :)

Comment: getting same records before and after removing data from database into HashMap... I am not able to remove data from HashMap whereas data has been removed from database table... please check updated code

Comment: @Oreo Try this for removing:        _listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).remove(childPosition);

Comment: I believe you want to delete a single entry from child list, but what you are doing is removing the key "childPosition" from the HashMap.

Comment: Thank you so much :) +1K

Answer (score 0):

Before you call the notifyDataSetChanged(), you have to reload the list backing your adapter. notifyDataSetChanged() lets the adapter know that the list has changed and hence to reload the list. But you have to load the backing list for the adapter for the list to show the views.